# Why do we have to select the operating system when creating a Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

When we want to create a new VM in VirtualBox, we have to select the OS and the version like in screen below:

[image]

But we are really creating a bare metal machine for the OS at this stage, the actual OS would be installed in the next step when we setup the VM.

So my question is why do we have to select the OS at this stage? Is it just for description? Does it has any other particular purpose?

Comment: VMware does the same thing. I checked my own system here. I think it makes the disk for the OS to be installed, but then the disk type can be altered when you create the machine. I do not do this step. I create the machine when I have the OS to install and use the option to use only the disk space needed. I do not allocate all the space at the beginning.

Comment: @John Good to know VMware does the same thing but trying to make sense of it why this step is needed. It doesn't really look like it does anything significant with this info. All other settings are the same. At most it would be a flag in the VM that this is _intended to be_ so and so OS.

Comment: I am not sure if the step is truly needed or just some preparation that can be changed anyway. It is a design issue and I just cannot say conclusively.

Answer (score 1):

In VirtualBox you do not have to select a specific OS when creating a virtual machine. You can select "Other" for both the Type and Version. But selecting a specific OS provides some significant advantages.

It shows the OS installed. This is particularly important if there are several virtual machines, each with a different OS. It is also useful when the individual creating the virtual machine is not the primary user.

It enables VirtualBox to provide reasonable default settings for memory and disk size. This is particularly important for inexperienced users who may not be familiar with the system requirements of the OS.

It does basic configuration appropriate for the OS to be installed. Some of these settings must be appropriate or the OS may not install or operate correctly and the user would not know why. Some of these settings should not be changed after an OS is installed.

None of this is critical but it does make things easier, particularly for inexperienced users.

Comment: +1 for `It enables VirtualBox to provide reasonable default settings for memory and disk size`, that's definitely right.